# C++ rewrite file

Tags: c++

I have a C++ class where many of the assignments involve copying and pasting code from the book. Problem is that the format of the book makes this a very tedious task. When I copy and paste, there are extraneous numbers and spaces on the left of the code, and parts of the code are misaligned.  I'm looking to write a C++ program to read a file (probably a .txt) to reformat the code and delete the numbers on the side.

However, I've been searching cplusplus.com, and can't figure out what library to import, so that I can open and edit the file.  I'd appreciate a point in the right direction, and any tips for text editing any of you might have.  Thank you.

Comment: This is not the appropriate place to ask this question.

Comment: I definitely believe that some examples in book are about reading/writing files, but to copy them you probably need to write your tool... looks like uroboros

Comment: It's not related to c++ but there are many 'online c++ formatters' (google it).

Comment: Thanks Nathaniel for your constructive comment /s, where would be a better place?

Comment: Candidly, this site generally requires that you post code you have written.  This is likely a question you should ask a classmate or the instructor.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is for a class, I don't want to give you too much of an answer, but you will need to include file streaming and input output streaming. I would also look at the getLine function.

As far as the editing of the text coming in, you can format the strings so that the first x digits are lopped off. It is not the prettiest, but it sounds like you are in the early parts of the class, so that may not be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

To remove the line numbers:  copy and paste the code into a decent text editor with a Block Select feature ( I use textpad ) Enable block selection and select the line numbers.  Delete them.  Save the result.

To pretty format the code: copy and paste the code ( minus line numbers ) into a decent IDE ( integrated development environment - I use code::blocks )  Reformat the code.